# C# and MySQL | How to check if record has been signed twice already?

Tags: c#

**Goal:**

I am trying to get the count from a query into a variable. With the variable I will be to determine whether it was signed twice or not.

**Code:**

```
 //Check if multiple records signed twice alreay
int CheckRecord = 0;
//Query to return number of records
string userCheckQuery = "select count(*) from request join verify on request_id = request.id where request.id = @checking;";

//Connection string
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
    {
    conn.Open();
    using (var checkUser = new MySqlCommand(userCheckQuery, conn))
    {
        checkUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checking", dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        CheckRecord = (Int32)checkUser.ExecuteScalar();

    }
    }

    //If less than 2, continue, else stop
    if (CheckRecord < 2)
    {
    }
```

**Details**

I know for fact this code is not right by using this line of code `CheckRecord = (Int32)checkUser.ExecuteScalar();`. Because it throws in an error `System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'`.

**Question:**

Does anyone know a better solution to get the count from a query and create an if statement with it?

Also, Im I on the right lines of coding it correctly?

**Desired Outcome**

`if (CheckRecord is less than 2 continue) else (CheckRecord is 2 then stop)`

Comment: `CheckRecord = Convert.ToInt32(checkUser.ExecuteScalar());`  Also, don't use `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Why don't use your SQL to filter only those who alreado have two or more records? it will be much easier.

Comment: What do you mean @David?

Comment: @Zer0 your code worked.. thanks :D

Comment: use your sql to get only those who already have two or more signatures. 
Something like
select count(*) from request join verify on request_id = request.id where request.id = checking having count(*) > 1
I don't know if it is syntax correct, I have no BDD to test it right now.
If not, this must work
select count(*), request.id from request join verify on request_id = request.id where request.id = checking group by request.id having count(*) > 1
This last version implies you should change your executescalar due to select returns two fields.

Comment: If that answers your question completely I'll post as an answer.  If not, please edit the question so I (or someone else) can post a more complete answer.

Comment: @David ahh I see! - In future I will think to use both sides instead of just C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, you can use your SQL to already filter data needed. 
Something like

```
 select count(*) 
   from request 
   join verify on request_id = request.id 
  where request.id = checking 
 having count(*) > 1
```